# Can't connect to localhost on mac WebServer from other computers on same local network

Tags: macos, webserver, localhost, ifconfig

When I execute `ifconfig` in terminal, I see under the en0 > inet > 192.168.0.10 which is my machine's ip, but when I enter it into my PC or iPhone's browser, it doesn't work, how do I connect to my localhost from my Mac? All machines are running on the same local network

**UPDATE**

[Output](http://pasted.co/484b390c) of `netstat -an` in terminal

Comment: Do you get any response or does it just say that there is nothing there?

Comment: On my iPhone it says err_connection_timed_out @Richie086

Comment: What exact web service are you running on the Mac? In the Terminal, what is the output of `netstat -an` for tcp connections in the `LISTEN` state?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your first question, but Apache? I have added the output please check my post @fideli

Comment: _HOW_ are you wanting to connect - ie what program or service or protocol are you trying to connect to/with/using.   There are _LOTS_ of ways to connect to a system, including over HTTP or HTTPS (web), file sharing, FTP, SSH for a start

Comment: Oh, i want to connect to an app I built with Laravel, I do `php artisan serve` and can access it from my mac at localhost:8000, so I'd want to access it from another computer at 192.168.0.10:8000 or something similar @davidgo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at https://serverfault.com/questions/581529/why-isnt-laravels-php-artisan-serve-server-being-accessible-from-the-www-on-ii  - This says you should not be using this for production - but try starting it with "

```
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
```

To allow it to bind to the external IP address.

You will also need to ensure your firewall allows this traffic to pass through if your firewall is on.  For experimental purposes, maybe the best thing to do is to turn it off by setting it off in "Security & Privacy" under "System Settings"

Comment: I did that, and my mac printed `Laravel development server started on http://0.0.0.0:8000/`

Then I tried pinging from my other machine and got `Destination host unreachable`

Comment: I will award my bounty in 6 hours, when I am allowed

Comment: I've spent days playing with apache and python's SimpleHTTPServer only to find out it was that MAC OS firewall option.  (I had even gotten my old windows laptop out and my iphone connected fine to IT.)

Comment: Jesus I'm always forgetting about this.

Answer (score 0):

**It depends on what you mean by *connect***. If you are attempting to connect via a specific protocol, you may need to specify the port (unless it is the [default port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) for the protocol you are using).

[If you do not have an open socket for the given port, any request to your machine on that port will go unanswered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket).

you can try `ping 192.168.0.10` from your PC terminal (`cmd.exe`) to see if your Mac is reachable. If it isn't:

- your **netmask** configuration might be messed up, or simply non-conducive to your PC seeing your Mac
- your router may be malfunctioning
- your configurations might be conflicting
- one of the configurations may be incorrect
- your router's **routing table** may be out of date (unlikely)

If it is:

- make sure you know the port you want
- make sure your Mac is handling the port you want

Hope this helps!

- Ethan

*sources: CISCO certified networking course, Wikipedia, personal experience*

Comment: I tried `ping 192.168.0.10` and It said `Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1642ms TTL=64` four times, every time with different 'time', respectively 1643ms, 2ms, 2ms, 11ms.

Then it just printed the ping statistics, what can I do from here?

Comment: it means you are already reaching the machine, but what are you expecting to do? Are you gonna to hold HTTP server? So you need a HTTP server software to listing on port 80